How does one access a closure property in the watch window in the browser debugging tools?
If I'm sitting at a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger in some JavaScript code, I can see the value of one of the function parameters in the "Scope" section inside a Closure:

Is there anything I can type into the Watch section to see that same value? I tried the parameter name (didn't work), I tried e (didn't work), I tried Yn.e and it also didn't work.
Thanks!

Maybe try right-clicking on the variable, there may be a menu that allows you to watch the variable.

Afaik the watch expressions need to be JS, which doesn't allow accessing closure scopes. If e doesn't work (because it's not in scope, or shadowed) you're probably out of luck

AFAICT, there must be an additional reference to the parameter name within the scope of the breakpoint for the expression-watching feature to evaluate it. So… this wouldn't work when watching e: (e) => { debugger; }, but variations of this would: (e) => { debugger; e.type; }

This question is similar to: Why does Chrome debugger think closed local variable is undefined?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
